# Why does windows try and use a network with no internet when connected to two networks at once?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-adapter

I have known for a long while now that when Windows is connected to two networks at a time, it will split traffic between them in an effort to increase the speed or something like that. However, even when a network has zero internet connectivity, and Windows knows it has no internet connectivity, it will still try to use both networks for internet traffic, instead of defaulting to the one with the internet connection, resulting in lost data and longer loading times. That's at least my understanding of what is occurring from what I see.

Why does it do that, and is there a way to prevent it short of disconnecting from the offline connection one way or another. I have a dedicated router for my VR headset to connect to so I don't have to run cables through my house but I don't always remember to turn it off.

Comment: Windows will not split traffic. It will use the route with the lowest cost (metric). No other data is involved in this decision.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to remove the default gateway on the interface without internet access.

Other than that Daniel B answered correctly, that the metric is the operative factor, which leads to the second solution to manually set the metrics for the network interfaces.